# Adding field to my database

Tags: asp.net, database, insert

I have a class called `Customer` with a string field `name`.

I want to save this field to the database and I try do do it like that:

```
string command = "insert into Customer values ('customer.name')";
```

(`Customer customer`)

The problem is that the value that saved into the data base is `customer.name` and not the value that is saved in the 'name' field.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please follow.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a mistake in string concatenation. You can update your query like following(caution: This approach can lead to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)):

```
string comand = "insert into Customer values ('"+ customer.name +"')";
```

**My suggestion:**

using parameterized query like following:

```
string connectionString = "You connection string";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        //
        // Description of SQL command:
        // @CustomerName must be added as a new SqlParameter.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Customer values (@CustomerName)", connection))
        {
             //
             // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
             //
             command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerName", customer.Name));

             //Execute your query
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I know this is SQL Injection but this is what he asked. Isn't it?

Comment: I just point out the error he was doing. SQL Injection is a different topic.(Out of scope of this question)

Comment: ok thank you but i have a new problem now
it is show me an error on this line :
command.Close();
he didnt recognized the Colse

Comment: Use connection.Close(); in it's place.

Comment: @marc_s this is the answer to the question at hand, the question wasn't 'how should I do inserts'